# map/set iterator not dereferencable. Multimap container isse

Tags: c++, graph, multimap

I'm geting this error message `map/set iterator not dereferencable` When trying to get value by key in `multimap`. In this code I'm trying to show nonoriented graph represented by adjacency list (`vector<Vertex*> vertexList`)

```
void NonOrGraph::show() {

    cout << endl;
    multimap<int, int> used;
    for (int i = 0; i < vertexList.size(); i++) {
        if (vertexList[i]->adjMap.empty()) {
            cout << vertexList[i]->index << " isolated";
        } else {
            for(map<Vertex*, int>::iterator it = vertexList[i]->adjMap.begin();
                                                 it != vertexList[i]->adjMap.end();
                                                 it++)
            {

                int from = vertexList[i]->index;
                int to   = it->first->index;
                int weight = it->second;

                used.insert(pair<int, int>(from, to)); 
                if (used.find(to)->second != from) {
                    cout << from << " <--(" << weight << ")--> " << to << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "\n\n";

}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely here:

```
if (used.find(to)->second != from) {
```

If `to` is not in `used`, `used.find()` will return `used.end()`, which you then dereference. It is undefined behavior to dereference the `end()` iterator, which in this case manifests by giving you a runtime error.

You have to check the iterator against `end()` first:

```
std::multimap<int, int>::iterator multi_it = used.find(to);
if (multi_it != used.end() && multi_it->second != from) {
//                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                        now, it's safe to dereference
```

Comment: thx, but needed element may be in the end of map. Is the best way to overcome this case by adding to the end some symbolic value?

Comment: @Arsen `end()` does not mean it's the last element in the map, it means it's not in the map.